# How to plot the distance between nodes networkx

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, networkx

I have 20 nodes and I want to draw a graph using networkx. I computed the distance between the nodes. How can I show the distances I computed between pairs of nodes on graph (networkx)?

this is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import torch_geometric


g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
```

I got graph with randomly distance:

[image]

Comment: What does _"How can I show the distance I computed between the nodes on graph"_ mean? There isn't _one_ distance between nodes, only several distances between pairs of nodes?

Comment: I computed the distance between pairs of nodes...

Comment: You can pass a `pos` kwarg to `nx.draw` as a dictionnary with node as key and position as value